# How do I return a unchanged variable everytime it exceeds a certain number?

Tags: java, methods, int

Im trying to get the variable x to return its value after the addition when its below 10 and I want it to return its unchanged value everytime it reaches a number >10. What did I do wrong?

The unsuccessful Code:

```
public class test {

  static int method(int r){

      int x = 0;
      x = x + r;
      if (x <=10) { 

      if (x >=10)    
          return x;}  //unsure about this part of the Code.
  return x;
  } 

        public static void main(String[] arg) {

        int i = method(4);
        System.out.println(i); //want it to output 4

         i = method(7); 
        System.out.println(i); //want it to output 4 because 4+7= 12. 12 >10

         i = method(5); //want it to output 9
        System.out.println(i);} 
  }
```

Comment: You have `if (x >=10)` under `if (x <=10)` without any intermediate change to `x`. That's surely wrong.

Comment: you need to define `x` outside the method, otherwise it is local and does not remember its value across different calls.

Comment: Please format your code properly. To your question... you basically just return `r` (since `x` is initialized as `0`)... so given your description, you want to return `r` iff. `r < 10` and `0` otherwise? A remark: class names should always start with an uppercase letter (`test` -> `Test`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a local variable. If you want it to retain its value between calls, you'll have to save it in a data member (in this case, a static member, since `method` is static):

```
private static int x = 0;
static int method(int r) {
    int temp = x + r;
    if (temp < 10) {
        x = temp;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have problam in your method change to this :

```
public class test1 {

    static int x = 0;
    static int method(int r) {

        int t = x + r;
        if (t < 10) {
            x = t;
        }
        return x;
    }


            public static void main(String[] arg) {

            int i = method(4);
            System.out.println(i); //want it to output 4

             i = method(7); 
            System.out.println(i); //want it to output 4 because 4+7= 12. 12 >10

             i = method(5); //want it to output 9
            System.out.println(i);} 
      }
```

Output :

```
4
4
9
```